# container.children doesn't work whitin an event function of JQM

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
<fieldset data-role='controlgroup' id='V14'>
<input id ='V14_1' type='radio' name='V14' value='1'><label for='V14_1'>UNO</label>
<input id ='V14_2' type='radio' name='V14' value='2'><label for='V14_2'>DOS</label>
<input id ='V14_3' type='radio' name='V14' value='3'><label for='V14_3'>TRES</label>
</fieldset>
```

I just want to sort the radio buttons using this function, which works perfectly:

```
var container = $("#V14");
var cbs = container.children('input');
var entry;
for (var i=0;i< cbs.length;++i){
   entry = $(cbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * cbs.length)]);
   entry.add(entry.next()).appendTo(container);
}
```

...however when I insert that piece of code within a JQM event it doesn't!

```
$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow',function(e,ui){
```

NOW IT DOES NOT WORKS:

```
   var container = $("#V14");
   var cbs = container.children('input');
   var entry;
   for (var i=0;i< cbs.length;++i){
      entry = $(cbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * cbs.length)]);
      entry.add(entry.next()).appendTo(container);
   }
})
```

The even 'pagecontainerbeforeshow' gets perfectly triggered, and I can debug the code inside.......When I check cbs.length it gets ZERO!...But If I run the same code outside this event, cbs.length gets 3!...My god, where is the misktake?

Answer (score 0):

First, the page container events are on the BODY tag not document.
Second, at that point, jQM has enhanced the fieldgroup, so you need to sort the .ui-radio DIV instead of the underlying input. Finally, destroy and re-enhance the controlgroup so the items are correctly redrawn:

```
$("body").on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(e, ui){
    var container = $("#V14");
    var cbs = container.find('.ui-radio');

    var entry;
    for (var i=0;i< cbs.length;++i){
       entry = $(cbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * cbs.length)]);
       entry.add(entry.next()).appendTo(container);
    }
    container.controlgroup("destroy").controlgroup();
});
```

> working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/mp4oqLcd/)**

Comment: ok, I just wonder what if in set of radio buttons it was a SELECT (drop down menu)

Comment: @AbrahamPetit, then you would resort the OPTIONs and refresh the selectmenu widget: .selectmenu("refresh", true)  http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh